# Why url query component is not removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrap the `href` to URL, and try to remove one component, remove with `delete`, but component does not disappear. Do you know why?

```js
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let p = url.searchParams['postId'+$(".selected").length];
delete p;
window.location = url.toString();
```

---

I tried this:

```
const filteredItems = url.searchParams.filter(key => url.searchParams[key] == postID);
let key = filteredItems.keys.first;
url.searchParams.delete(key);
```

but it says

> Uncaught TypeError: url.searchParams.filter is not a function

---

I tried now this expression, but `filter` does not work, do you have any idea why?

```js
function togglePost(postID) {
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const filteredItems = Object.keys(url.searchParams).filter(key =>
        url.searchParams[key] == postID
    );
    let key = filteredItems.keys.first;
```

Comment: I think you might be better off looking at [URLSearchParams.delete()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete` operator deletes *properties from objects*.

You are trying to delete a variable. This fails silently.

To delete something from a URLSearchParams object, use [the `delete` **method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete):

```js
let url = new URL('http://example.com/foo.cgi?a=1&b=2');
console.log(url.toString());
url.searchParams.delete('a');
console.log(url.toString());
```

Comment: Not key, but value of the `searchParams`object is the known value. What do you think why filtering breaks?

Comment: It isn't an array, so it doesn't have a `filter` method. You're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/entries